# Using std::condition_variable with atomic<bool>

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

There are several questions on SO dealing with atomic, and other that deal with std::condition_variable. But my question if my use below is correct?

Three threads, one ctrl thread that does preparation work before unpausing the two other threads. The ctrl thread also is able to pause the worker threads (sender/receiver) while they are in their tight send/receive loops.
The idea with using the atomic is to make the tight loops faster in case the boolean for pausing is not set.

```
class SomeClass
{

public:
    //...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    // Disregard that data is public...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

    std::condition_variable cv; // UDP threads will wait on this cv until allowed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                // to run by ctrl thread.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    std::mutex cv_m;
    std::atomic<bool> pause_test_threads;
};

void do_pause_test_threads(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    if (!someclass->pause_test_threads)
    {
        // Even though we use an atomic, mutex must be held during                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        // modification. See documentation of condition variable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
        // notify_all/wait. Mutex does not need to be held for the actual                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        // notify call.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(someclass->cv_m);
        someclass->pause_test_threads = true;
    }
}

void unpause_test_threads(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    if (someclass->pause_test_threads)
    {
        {
            // Even though we use an atomic, mutex must be held during                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
            // modification. See documentation of condition variable                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            // notify_all/wait. Mutex does not need to be held for the actual                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            // notify call.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(someclass->cv_m);
            someclass->pause_test_threads = false;
        }
        someclass->cv.notify_all(); // Allow send/receive threads to run.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    }
}

void wait_to_start(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(someclass->cv_m); // RAII, no need for unlock.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    auto not_paused = [someclass](){return someclass->pause_test_threads == false;};
    someclass->cv.wait(lk, not_paused);
}

void ctrl_thread(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    // Do startup work                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    // ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    unpause_test_threads(someclass);

    for (;;)
    {
        // ... check for end-program etc, if so, break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        if (lost ctrl connection to other endpoint)
        {
            pause_test_threads();
        }
        else
        {
            unpause_test_threads();
        }
        sleep(SLEEP_INTERVAL);

    }

    unpause_test_threads(someclass);
}

void sender_thread(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    wait_to_start(someclass);
    ...
    for (;;)
    {
        // ... check for end-program etc, if so, break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        if (someclass->pause_test_threads) wait_to_start(someclass);
        ...
    }
}

void receiver_thread(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    wait_to_start(someclass);
    ...
    for (;;)
    {
        // ... check for end-program etc, if so, break;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        if (someclass->pause_test_threads) wait_to_start(someclass);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I looked through your code manipulating conditional variable and atomic, and it seems that it is correct and won't cause problems.

#### Why you should protect writes to shared variable even if it is atomic:

There could be problems if write to shared variable happens between checking it in predicate and waiting on condition. Consider following:

1. **Waiting thread** wakes spuriously, aquires mutex, checks predicate and evaluates it to `false`, so it must wait on cv again.
2. **Controlling thread** sets shared variable to `true`.
3. **Controlling thread** sends notification, which is not received by anybody, because there is no threads waiting on conditional variable.
4. **Waiting thread** waits on conditional variable. Since notification was already sent, it would wait until next spurious wakeup, or next time when controlling thread sends notification. Potentially waiting indefinetly.

Reads from shared atomic variables without locking is generally safe, unless it introduces [TOCTOU problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use).

In your case you are reading shared variable to avoid unnecessary locking and then checking it again after lock (in conditional `wait` call). It is a valid optimisation, called double-checked locking and I do not see any potential problems here.

You might want to check if `atomic<bool>` is lock-free. Otherwise you will have even more locks you would have without it.

Comment: It seems all x86_64 machines have lock-free atomic<bool>, also all other X86:es that have atomic compare-exchange for booleans. (I drew this conclusion from /usr/include/boost/atomic/detail/gcc-x86.hpp).

Comment: Based on the problem in your example, can it be said that you can safely write to the shared variable without locking a mutex **if** such a write will never result in predicates of waiting threads evaluating to `true` (imagine this can be guaranteed by the logic of the code itself), and only lock in cases when an "awakening" write is done?

Comment: "checks predicate and evaluates it to false, so it must wait on cv again." and then "not received by anybody, because there is no threads waiting":

the way it is written this suggests that there is in fact a thread waiting. I'm assuming that you mean that in step 1., after evaluating the predicate, but before proceeding to `wait()`, the other thread gets control and sets the variable to `true`?

Comment: @oarfish it... is exacly what is written. At point (2) controlling thread sets variable to true, at point (3) it sends notification and at (4) waiting thread finally gets the chance to `wait()`

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to treat the fact that variable is atomic independently of how it works with a condition variable.

If all code that interacts with the condition variable follows the usual pattern of locking the mutex before query/modification, and the code interacting with the condition variable does not rely on code that does not interact with the condition variable, it will continue to be correct even if it wraps an atomic mutex.

From a quick read of your pseudo-code, this appears to be correct.  However, pseudo-code is often a poor substitute for real code for multi-threaded code.

The "optimization" of only waiting on the condition variable (and locking the mutex) when an atomic read says you might want to may or may not be an optimization.  You need to profile throughput.

Answer (score -1):

atomic data doesn't need another synchronization, it's basis of lock-free algorithms and data structures.

```
void do_pause_test_threads(SomeClass *someclass)
{
    if (!someclass->pause_test_threads)
    {
        /// your pause_test_threads might be changed here by other thread
        /// so you have to acquire mutex before checking and changing
        /// or use atomic methods - compare_exchange_weak/strong,
        /// but not all together                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(someclass->cv_m);
        someclass->pause_test_threads = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In general, yes, but in this case, no. Check the documentation for usage of C++11 condition variable, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable

Comment: It is not a problem of simultaneous change (assigment to atomic cannot cause data race). Requirement for mutex is because if spurious wakeup and threads execution interleaves just right, waiting thread might miss the notification and enter infinite wait.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: OK, thanks for comment. Maybe care to elaborate and maybe make it into a full-blown answer? In my code, I make all changes under a mutex, but read the atomic boolean without mutex in the tight loops.

Comment: @ErikAlapää In your case, your reads are not relied upon in a sense.  The issue with atomic variables and condition code without mutexes happens when you try to *rely* on the atomicity during the "condition variable" communication system: if you do so, it is easy to end up with a possible window where your listening threads are waiting on a variable that has already been signaled.