# Is owning the lock required to request a stop while waiting on a condition_variable_any with stop_token?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stl, condition-variable

While waiting on a condition variable, the thread changing the state of the predicate must own the lock, so the update isn't missed during the wakeup. According to the documentation, this is necessary, even while using atomic variables.
However I'm not certain if `request_stop()` already handles it correctly.

So the question is, which of the two options is the correct and standard conforming one?

`~jthread()` naturally doesn't take a lock to `request_stop()`, but then I don't understand where the difference between a `stop_token` and an atomic shared variable is. And thereby, how one of them requires the lock, while the other doesn't.

```cpp
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>


std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable_any cv;

void waitingThread(std::stop_token st){
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
    std::cout<<"Waiting"<<std::endl;
    cv.wait(lk, st, [](){return false;});
    std::cout<<"Awake"<<std::endl;
}

void withoutLock(){
    std::jthread jt{waitingThread};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    jt.request_stop();
}

void withLock(){
    std::jthread jt{waitingThread};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        jt.request_stop();
    }
}

int main(){
    withoutLock();
    withLock();
}
```

[std::condition_variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) specifies:

> Even if the shared variable is atomic, it must be modified while owning the mutex to correctly publish the modification to the waiting thread.

[std::condition_variable_any::wait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable_any/wait),
[std::stop_token](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token)
and
[std::stop_source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_source)
do not specify, if the interrupt of the wait is guaranteed register the change in the stop state.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. The thread changing the state of the predicate is the one that signals the condition variable, not the one that waits on it.

Comment: The question was, if that signaling thread needs to aquire the lock for the stop_request. As we later on figured out, does the stop_token and condition_variable_any implementation handle the locking themselves and no additional steps are required by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While waiting on a condition variable, the thread changing the state of the predicate must own the lock, so the update isn't missed during the wakeup.

> ... do not specify, if the interrupt of the wait is guaranteed register the change in the stop state.

The issue isn't exactly *missing* the update, but going back to sleep after the `notify` has happened and before checking the predicate again.

The sequence in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36130475/212858) is the problematic one.

> According to the documentation, this is necessary, even while using atomic variables. However I'm not certain if `request_stop()` already handles it correctly.

The shared state itself is synchronized just fine: [thread.stoptoken.intro/5](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.stoptoken#intro-5) says

> Calls to the functions `request_­stop`, `stop_­requested`, and `stop_­possible` do not introduce data races.
> A call to `request_­stop` that returns `true` synchronizes with a call to `stop_­requested` on an associated `stop_­token` or `stop_­source` object that returns true.

The wait-predicate loop described in [thread.condvarany.intwait](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition.condvarany#thread.condvarany.intwait) would have the same problem:

```
while (!stoken.stop_requested()) {
  if (pred())
    return true;
  wait(lock);
}
return pred();
```

if `request_stop` is called between the first line and the `wait(lock)`, then `stop_requested()` will become `true` and the condition variable be notified while nobody is waiting. Then we'll start waiting, for a notification that never comes.

If `request_stop` can only be called while the mutex is released inside `wait`, we'll always be guaranteed to check `stop_requested()` before sleeping again.

In fact though, the GNU ISO C++ library does this for us: `std::condition_variable_any` has an additional internal mutex used to synchronize the `request_stop` callback (which just notifies the condvar in the requesting thread) correctly with the wait-predicate loop. So, **if** that behaviour is required by the standard, you don't need your own mutex here.

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I was digging through the code again and found that stop_token registers a stop callback on wait, which takes the lock and notifies correctly. So it doesn't apply in this case, as the condition variable provides the necessary internals.
I'll post a self answer later, but thanks for taking your time

Comment: Aha, I see the `condition_variable_any` implementation has its own additional internal mutex which synchronizes the `request_stop` callback with the `stop_requested` check. That's far from clearly described in the standard IMO.

Comment: In the implementations I've seen, it just uses the same mutex that it's waiting on. Maybe they expected the wording to be absolute enough and leave the implementation details to the retailers.

Comment: With that edit I'm going to accept your answer, as I prefer the wording a lot over mine.

Answer (score 0):

All `stop_token` overloads of `condition_variable_any::wait` and the timed variants, register a `stop_callback`, which captures the Lockable object. Then on `request_stop()` the callback is executed, taking the lock and notifying the waiting threads, therefore eliminating missing updates.